# Mirroring 2 out of 3 HDMI displays (2 monitors and 1 TV)

Tags: nvidia

I have a Nvidia Geforce GTX 770 and use 2 BENQ 1080p monitors. I would like to mirror my other screen (Television 1080p) with one of my BENQ screens.

I have read something about saving the config file and put some code into it. First I would like to know something about the config saving and if it's safe for my GPU.

Also, how do I save the config because I have already got the mirroring done but it doesn't save. I had read in the Terms that it's normal but possible??? Please could someone explain that to me?

Answer (score 1):

```
xrandr --output HDMI1 --auto --rotate left --output HDMI2 --auto --rotate left --right-of HDMI1 --output HDMI3 --auto --rotate left --right-of HDMI2
```

You have to "play" with these commands, I have done it and it worked.